# Locomotive CMS :: How to check which DB we are using in website from admin panel

Tags: locomotivecms

We have a website developed using Locomotive CMS and I have access only to its admin panel. How I will get know whether it is using MYSQL or Mongo DB.

I am new to this CMS. Could you anyone guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocomotiveCMS v3 (and versions below v3) uses MongoDB.
If you need more help, please go to one of our Gitter chat rooms (https://gitter.im/locomotivecms/v3?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link).